# Which part of some LED TV screens acts as two gratings crossed at non-straight angle?

Tags: lcd, light

Some modern LED TVs display the following diffraction pattern (photos taken from [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/270890/21441)):

[image: diffration pattern of a LED TV]

In my answer to [another question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/381233/21441) about the origin of this pattern I explained that this should be due to two diffraction gratings crossed at a non-straight angle, since the inverse Fourier transform of an idealized reproduction of the pattern (rotated by 90°, see the answer in the link above for the pattern) looks like this:

[image: inverse Fourier transform of the idealized diffraction pattern]

But if we look at a close-up, we'll see a simple square grid of pixels, so we can't easily see the crossed gratings:

[image: close-up of the pattern]

I've now gone to a electronics shop and found several such screens, so I can now name exact models and provide more close-ups. One of them is LG 49LK5400. Here's what its pattern looks like, with an image, so that the lit pixels are also visible. Note that the photo is a good representation of what the human naked eye sees (up to compression artifacts). Click for full resolution.

[image: LG 49LK5400]

Another screen with a very prominent cross (in addition to some other patterns) is that of HP Spectre 13-af006ur. It has much smaller pixels, so I couldn't resolve them.

[image: HP Spectre 13-af006ur]

My guess is that this effect might be caused by the arrangement of the conductors powering the pixels. Or it may be the pattern from one of the layers of light spreading system of backlight.

But I may be wrong, so I thought it's better to ask experts: what is the actual part of the LCD screen which results in this type of crossed-gratings-like behavior?

Comment: Obligatory comic strip: https://xkcd.com/1814/

Comment: See [this Photography.SE question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/53820/71533) for more details.

Comment: @Ruslan Is the simple square grid of pixels visible to the naked eye?

Comment: @TomCarpenter Moiré is completely unrelated to diffraction patterns. And the family of patterns in question are visible by the naked eye in the same way the camera sees them, and are modelled as such in the paper I linked to.

Comment: @AndrewMorton please see the update: I've added a photo of what I've now seen, and it does represent it faithfully.

Answer (score 1):

The hexagonal array pattern of AMLCD fine pitch pixels lends itself to the 30,60 deg aliasing patterns found in your photography in LG 4k/5k monitors.  The pixel emissions may be orthogonal, but here we are looking at highly reflective vectors under a non-reflective coated glass.

Technically it is best called a Fraunhofer diffraction pattern.

In 35mm SLR photography,  the aperture shape can cause this with edge diffraction.  In software, it is called the Starburst or North Star Effect filter. 
[image: Just as the] 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OLED

Comment: If you look at the photos in the OP—those with resolved pixels—you'll see that they are in a rectangular pattern, not hexagonal.

Comment: the like colour pixel emitters are orthogonal but the reflection of white flash LEDs of light picks up on the recursive vector patterns of reflectance in spite  of AR glass coatings.

Comment: Could you elaborate how exactly the structure of the screen is arranged so as to generate this pattern?

Comment: did you want an nano-sized image of reflectance of each element?  You can do that without a flash using bright diffused ambient light with a good macro camera

Comment: I wanted a schematic structure of the panel with a clear indication of which layers interact to generate the pattern. In particular, I have no idea what "reflective vectors" you mean: what they are, what they are for etc.

Comment: I dont have that structure but if you took a macro photo of one then apply Fraunhofer Difraction Theory with polarized non-reflective glass coatings then you will discover more.  http://scienceworld.wolfram.com/physics/FraunhoferDiffraction.html  But you may never fully understand until you study the physics

Answer (score -2):

As has been mentioned in the comments, this is not a "diffraction pattern" (i.e., a pattern produced by a [diffraction grating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffraction_grating)), it is a [Moiré pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moir%C3%A9_pattern) resulting from the [interaction](https://xkcd.com/1814/) of the display grid with the digital camera's sensor grid.

In fact, it is three separate patterns, one each for the red, green and blue pixels in each grid. Since the color elements are slightly offset from each other in both grids, the resulting Moiré patterns are offset, too. They blend together to produce the same "rainbow" effect that you get from a diffraction grating, but via a completely different mechanism.

You won't see this pattern when you look at the display directly with your eyes. You also won't see it if you take a picture of the display with a film camera.

Comment: Nope, it's not Moiré. See the updated question. One of the photos resolves the pixels so that the Moiré would disappear, but the pattern is still present. Also, exactly the same pattern is visible with the naked eye, and human retina doesn't have too regular a pattern of photoreceptors (at least not to result in stable Moiré with a screen grid); saccades would also result in flicker, which I didn't observe.

Comment: I think I know why you thought it was three patterns: due to the first photo. But I suppose that one was done with a fluorescent lamp, whose lined spectrum results in these separate diffraction maxima (note how they are elongated all in the same direction: this is the shape of the lamp). The other photos I did now with a phone flash don't have this separation.

Comment: It is not a photographic  Moiré pattern but a pattern of pixel hexagonal angular displacement, -1